# Using CSS & HTML with MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, html, css, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

My CSS formatting is lost when i use it with MFMailComposeViewController.  Below is my sample code. I just insert my table data under the body section.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #customers {
      font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      width: 100%;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    #customers td,
    #customers th {
      font-size: 1em;
      text-align: right;
      border: 1px solid #999999;
      padding: 10px 25px 5px 25px;
    }
    #customers th {
      font-size: 1.1em;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px 25px 5px 25px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      color: #000000;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  %@

</body>

</html>
```

I am setting the "isHTML=YES" while composing the email. Am i missing something or is this method of using CSS not supported on the iphone using MFMailComposeViewController

Comment: It helps if you format your post sensibly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear, but are you putting your CSS inside the `<body>` or `<head>`?  I believe `MFMailComposeViewController` needs to have CSS defined inside the `<body></body>` tags.

Comment: Except `<style>` inside `<body>` isn't valid HTML, IIRC. Even if it does get through, it might not render correctly in all mail clients (and it night get stripped by webmail - otherwise it's likely to be a security risk). I'd just bite the bullet and use the `style` attribute.

Comment: Ahh ... you just made my day. Yes the CSS was in the wrong section. Thanks alot :-)

Comment: hmmm ... the formatting is present when i view the email on the iphone but its lost when i view it in gmail in the browser? Any ideas

Comment: not sure, did you do what @tc said? and used inline `style=''`?

Comment: Gmail strips a lot style items out automatically.